# .BAT to filter data in a csv with a line containing in the 3rd token

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have this sample csv file

Alvin,am,7,11,math,sci

Mary,am,7,11,math,sci

Andrew,am,11,3,english,history

I want to create this resulting csv

Alvin,am,7,11,math,sci

Mary,am,7,11,math,sci

I already have this code

```
@echo off

FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=," %%1 IN (abcd.csv) DO IF %%3 EQU 7 ECHO %%1 %%2 %%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 >> output.csv
```

I readied the output.csv considering that I will use the redirection code `>>` which appends rather than `>` which creates. Please let me know why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace spaces by commas:

```
@echo off
del output.csv
FOR /F "eol=- tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=," %%1 IN (abcd.csv) DO IF %%3 EQU 7 ECHO %%1,%%2,%%3,%%4,%%5,%%6 >> output.csv
```

And you'll have expected result:

```
Alvin,am,7,11,math,sci 
Mary,am,7,11,math,sci
```

Also it is better to delete output.csv before appending (to avoid duplication of data in case of multiple call of your script).